# Python - From while loop to for loop

Tags: python

How can I make a for loop instead of this while loop?

```
count = 2
data = ["string 1", "some quotation", "ugly phrase"]

while (count != len(data[0])):
    # Do some stuff
    count += 1
```

I am watching tutorials, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: how is `count` changed in the while-block? Does `data[0]` change inside the while-block?

Comment: Depends on how you modify `count` inside loop. Show us [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: data[0] doesn't change, and I use count += 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As given, you can't.  A `for` loop requires that you have a loop control variable that increments on each iteration.  Since you have no change in the value of count or the length of `data[0]`, all you have is an infinite loop.

However, if your structure were something like this, you could convert:

```
count = 2
data = ["First element of data", "Second element of data"]

while count != len(data[0]):
    print(data[count])
    count += 1
```

The `for`-loop form:

```
for count in range(2, len(data[0])):
    print(data[count])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for count in range(2, len(data[0])):
    # code
```